# Hibernate doesn't return proper objects in inner join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on Spring MVC application that uses Hibernate. One of my requests in SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT work_order.* FROM work_order
inner join user
on
work_order.user_id = user.id
and
user.user_name = 'Jenna'
```

and I do get a result as a row of workorders. When I'm trying to do the same with Hibernate I get five objects(which is correct) but can't convert into WorkoOrder objects.
Here's my Hibernate request:

```
List<WorkOrder> workorders =  (List<WorkOrder>)currentSession.createQuery(
"from WorkOrder w inner join w.user as u where user_name=:tempName")
.setParameter("tempName", tempName).getResultList();
```

Where tempName is a parameter. I do get objects, but can't cast them to Workorder, probably because Hibernate returns Workorders and Users combined. How to fix this so only Workorders will be returned?
Update: User is mapped in WorkOrder

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = true)
private User user;
```

Comment: If in your WorkOrder model you don't have mapped the user, I'd recommend you to do so

Comment: Share your WorkOrder and User entities. "work_order.user_id = user.id" join should be taken care by the relation mapping you define there.

Comment: @cristianorbs I do have the user mapped in my WorkOrder

Comment: Would you change your HQL query to `select w from WorkOrder w inner join w.user as u where user_name=:tempName` and test it again. I know you can ignore select clause in HQL but I prefer having it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HQL does not have a `select` clause.  If you want only the `WorkOrder` entities from the join you form, then you'll need to tell Hibernate so:

```
currentSession.createQuery(
        "select w from WorkOrder w inner join w.user as u where u.user_name=:tempName")
```

Comment: Ot they can change the query to `from WorkOrder w where w.user.user_name = :tempName`; but I prefer having select clause.

Comment: John, it worked and I get readable WorkOrder objects. Before  I was trying with "Select WorkOrder from..."

Comment: Acknowledged, @AmirPashazadeh, but although that will produce the same result, it's not semantically equivalent.  The OP forms a join from which to select his result (even if he omits the select clause), whereas your alternative instead uses a subquery in the `where` clause.  In principle, the two do not necessarily result in the same query plan.